# Concatenation problems with debug print macro under gcc

Tags: gcc, visual-c++, concatenation, c-preprocessor

To completely disable a debug output in c-source,
I usually define the following SIMPLE macro #1

`#define dprintf(args)`

To enable a debug output, I define macro #2 alternatively

`#define dprintf(args) printk##args`

The usage in source looks like:

`dprintf(("Irqs:%lu\n",irqs));`

A preprocessor should create following line if I use macro #2

`printk("Irqs:%lu\n",irqs);`

Under Windows Visual c++, there is no problem.

Using gcc version 4.4.1 (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9) under NETBEANS IDE 6.8,
I got the following error message:

`"printk" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token`

I tried the following under Linux

`#define dprintk(args...)  printk(args)`

This works only with 
`dprintf("Irqs:%lu\n",irqs);`

Visual C++ however does not know `args...`

I have to compile source code on windows
and Linux(386) platform alternatively.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not `#define dprintf(args) print args`  ?

The double parenthesis could have been added to replace the variadic macro in visual C++ : the preprocessor will handle macro invocation as if there was only one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The token pasting operator `##` can only be used to concatenate **tokens**, as its name implies. Some compilers, e.g. newer versions of gcc, enforce this more rigidly than others, as you have now discovered. As [philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18804/philippe) says, though, you don't actually need `##` in this particular example.